# iOS share extension disables preview

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-app-extension, ios-extensions

I am working on a share extension for Safari in iOS. We are using the stock UI from iOS, so extending the SLComposeServiceViewController.
I am also using a javascript to read the page content and set some parameters. The UI works fine showing the preview, if the JS file is not included. But as soon as I include the JS file, the preview is not showing up. Does anyone have any idea why this would not be showing up? Is there a configuration in the info.plist which enables the preview?

Answer (score 0):

I tried overloading loadPreviewView and building a custom preview and it showed. Also when debugging I found that when you use Javascript, the default preview is set to null. I guess it is mandatory to override the preview if JS is used.